# Subclass-friendly versions of built-in inmutable types?

Tags: python, subclass, built-in-types

This is such a common scenario when you just want to use a built-in type
only with a different string representation.  For instance, consider a
variable to store time measurements.  Typically you want a type that behaves
exactly like int or float for all intents and purposes except that when
coerced to string would produce a string formatted as HH:MM:SS or something like that.

It *should* be easy.  Unfortunately the following doesn't work

```
class ElapsedTime(float):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'XXX'
```

because the result of operations will be type float.  The
solution I know is rewrite a couple dozen methods, but this is most
impractical.  I can't believe there is no other way.  Why is there no
subclass-friendly UserInt, UserFloat types in the standard library intended to be
used in these situations?

Comment: I tried tinkering with `__getattribute__` but it was a mess.

Comment: I don't think it's quite as simple as you expect. For example, what type should the result of `1.0 + ElapsedTime(1)` be?

Comment: I think it should be the same type as the left-hand side object.

Comment: @ErnestA: Then I suspect the reason that there isn't one in the standard library, is that scalar-types-with-dimension in the standard library don't behave the way you want your scalar-types-with-dimension to behave. For example, `1 + datetime.timedelta()` isn't allowed. So if Python considers what you want to be "unnatural", it isn't going to provide a helper to do it. Feel free to publish yours once you've done it, it only has to be once each for int and float :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I think I could accept that as an answer.

Comment: @ErnestA: I only suspect, though, I don't feel that I know the Python design process well enough to be sure. Somebody who does and is can take the glory.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: class float2(float):
   ...:     def __init__(cls,val):
   ...:         return float.__init__(cls,val)
   ...:     def __str__(cls):
   ...:         return str(cls.real).replace(".",":")
   ...:     def __add__(cls,other):
   ...:         return float2(cls.real + other.real)
   ...:     ## similarly implement other methods...  
   ...:     

In [2]: float2(20.4)
Out[2]: 20.4

In [3]: print float2(20.4)
20:4

In [4]: x = float2(20.4) + float2(10.1)

In [5]: x
Out[5]: 30.5

In [6]: print x
30:5

In [7]: x = float2(20.4) + float(10.1)

In [8]: x
Out[8]: 30.5

In [9]: print x
30:5
```

does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, indeed it does, but I was looking for a simpler solution that does not involve rewriting `__add__` and a couple dozen methods more.

Comment: @ErnestA: i don't think there can be a easy/simple solution; also i am expecting that any python ninja to come up with a metaclass based solution but that is not an easy way! so easy task will be.. just go ahead and re-implement remaining methods.